# Bootstrap autosizing background images

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a background image on the header section autosize but it won't keep to aspect ratios. Here is an example, the image gets the bottom of it cut off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnNak.png or if I make it this size, space appears between it and the divs below header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO1kd.png I can almost seem to get it working but then it scales the picture to an odd aspect ratio and the image gets distorted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YtMd.png

I would like the header section to be the EXACT same size as the image, then have the image always showing all of the image (not cutting off a portion) and no space between header and the next divs.

This is the code I have for the HTML part:

```
    <header>
     T
    </header>
```

I believe this is the relevant CSS:

```
    header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background-image: url("ball.png");
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% auto;
    }
```

The site in question is here:

http://www.stoppiefail.com/boot/sites3/index.php

Comment: Can you show more of your html?

Answer (score 0):

You are using background-size: 100% auto; at the end which will be overwriting your previous code.

https://jsfiddle.net/26ejdss6/1/

```
div{
  width:400px;
  height:187px;
  background:url('http://ajgdirect.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/football.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Also, check out a neat plugin named backstretch.js. It's pretty nice for this kind of thing, especially when auto-sizing user added images in a CMS

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Background Image why not use an IMG tag with an absolute div on top of it.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="your/background/image.jpg" class="bg">
    <div class="headerContent">Your Header Content Goes Here</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
header img.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
header .headerContent {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I havn't tested this but it is just another way to do this outside of css, that would allow the height of the header never to be cut off.

Comment: The image then ends up being not responsive and doesn't resize depending on the screen.

Comment: Make header width: 100% as well, should help